# Access Control causing issues on different calls

Tags: javascript, ajax, access-control

The problem is that I am doing two ajax calls to the same website but with different webpages. Both the webpages are publicly available but the one is giving me Access-Control-Allow-Origin problems.

Call 1:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://osrm.jrgold.me/ParkingAvailability.php',
    data: '',
    crossDomain:true,
    success: function (response) {

    response = JSON.parse(response);
        for (var i = 0; i < response.lots.length; i++) {
            $('#' + response.lots[i].lot).html(response.lots[i].space);
        }
    },
    error: function (req, status, err) {

    }
});
```

Call 2:

$.getJSON(url , function(result){

```
            var x = result.route_summary.total_time/60;
            var data = {timeValue: x };

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://osrm.jrgold.me/prediction.php",
                data: data,
                crossDomain:true,
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                },
                error: function (req, status, err) {
                    //alert(req[1] + " " +status + ": " + err); 
                }
            });
        });
```

Like I said Call 1 works fine, but call 2 does not? I want to confirm it is not a problem with the permissions on the pages before I contact the owner of the pages.

Answer (score 0):

Response from `prediction.php` does not contain any `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. You can't work around that, it is in the competence of the site owner to allow or restrict the access to that resource.

More info in [How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work) question.

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned above the problem is with the server, more specifically with the php file. To solve `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` one can simply add:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

To the top of the php file.